# How do I join a list of integers?

Tags: python, list, join, append

My code's purpose is to list all possible 4 digit numbers (0000-9999), which it does easily.

```
i = 0
gen = []
while i <= 9999: 
    gen.append(i)
    i = i + 1

for cycle in gen:
    format(cycle, '04')
```

However, it prints each number on its own line, and I would like it to print in one big string. So my question is how do I join my list of integers so that it prints in one big string? I'm running Python 3.3 on Windows.

Comment: One-liner: `"".join([format(x, '04') for x in range(0,10000)])`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, there is a function `range`, which builds a generator for you; for example: `range(0,10000)` will generate 10,000 integers starting from 0 (0 to 9999 inclusive).

Note the range object is not a list, it's a function that will generate a list. You could make a list by doing:

```
list(range(0,10000))
```

Which gets you something like

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, ... 9999]
```

You can use a list comprehension to format each entry in the list:

```
[format(x, '04') for x in range(0,10000)]
```

Which gives you a list of strings like:

```
['0000', '0001', '0002', '0003', '0004', ...
```

Then to join a list of strings together, there is a function called `join`. You want to put the empty string between each number, so you call it like this:

```
"".join([format(x, '04') for x in range(0,10000)])
```

And you get your output:

```
00000001000200030004000500060007 ... 9999
```

Comment: Good answer. It's worth mentioning that you can join them with other characters or strings too `", ".join(...` would join them with a comma followed by a space between every one

Comment: I knew about the range and join functions, I just did not know how to implement them correctly in this case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Also you there is no need in constructing list in `join`. Just `"".join(format(x, '04') for x in range(0,10000))` would be enough and more efficient. See [generator expressions](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/).